# CActiveRecord and "Trying to get property of non-object" error

Tags: yii

In Yii Framework with a CGridView i need to read a value from CActiveRecord

the columns definition in CGridView is for columns:

```
'columns'=>array(
        ....
        array(
            'name'=>'rel_CustomerCampain.event_comment',
            'header'=>'Commenti Camp.',
            'value'=>'print_r($data->rel_CustomerCampain,false)'
        ),
.....
```

I have this object  $data->rel_CustomerCampain and I need to have the value in event_comment under the "_attributes:CActiveRecord:private" the value: 
********IneedOfThisValue*******

when I try 
  'value'=>'$data->rel_CustomerCampain->event_comment'

I have this error:
**"Trying to get property of non-object"**

anyone has idea?
thanks in advance....

```
[0] => customerCampain Object
        (
            [_md:CActiveRecord:private] => CActiveRecordMetaData Object
                (
                    [tableSchema] => CMysqlTableSchema Object
                        (
                            [schemaName] => 
                            [name] => tbl_customer_campain
                            [rawName] => `tbl_customer_campain`
                            [primaryKey] => id
                            [sequenceName] => 
                            [foreignKeys] => Array
                                (
                                    [id_campain] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => tbl_campain
                                            [1] => id
                                        )

                                    [id_customer] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => tbl_customer
                                            [1] => id
                                        )

                                )

                            [columns] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => id
                                            [rawName] => `id`
                                            [allowNull] => 
                                            [dbType] => int(10) unsigned
                                            [type] => string
                                            [defaultValue] => 
                                            [size] => 10
                                            [precision] => 10
                                            [scale] => 
                                            [isPrimaryKey] => 1
                                            [isForeignKey] => 
                                            [autoIncrement] => 1
                                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                        )

                                    [id_campain] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => id_campain
                                            [rawName] => `id_campain`
                                            [allowNull] => 
                                            [dbType] => int(10) unsigned
                                            [type] => string
                                            [defaultValue] => 
                                            [size] => 10
                                            [precision] => 10
                                            [scale] => 
                                            [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                            [isForeignKey] => 1
                                            [autoIncrement] => 
                                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                        )

                                    [id_customer] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => id_customer
                                            [rawName] => `id_customer`
                                            [allowNull] => 
                                            [dbType] => int(10) unsigned
                                            [type] => string
                                            [defaultValue] => 
                                            [size] => 10
                                            [precision] => 10
                                            [scale] => 
                                            [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                            [isForeignKey] => 1
                                            [autoIncrement] => 
                                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                        )

                                    [event_datetime] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => event_datetime
                                            [rawName] => `event_datetime`
                                            [allowNull] => 1
                                            [dbType] => datetime
                                            [type] => string
                                            [defaultValue] => 
                                            [size] => 
                                            [precision] => 
                                            [scale] => 
                                            [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                            [isForeignKey] => 
                                            [autoIncrement] => 
                                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                        )

                                    [event_type] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => event_type
                                            [rawName] => `event_type`
                                            [allowNull] => 1
                                            [dbType] => varchar(200)
                                            [type] => string
                                            [defaultValue] => 
                                            [size] => 200
                                            [precision] => 200
                                            [scale] => 
                                            [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                            [isForeignKey] => 
                                            [autoIncrement] => 
                                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                        )

                                    [event_status] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => event_status
                                            [rawName] => `event_status`
                                            [allowNull] => 1
                                            [dbType] => varchar(200)
                                            [type] => string
                                            [defaultValue] => 
                                            [size] => 200
                                            [precision] => 200
                                            [scale] => 
                                            [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                            [isForeignKey] => 
                                            [autoIncrement] => 
                                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                        )

                                    [event_comment] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                        (
                                            [name] => event_comment
                                            [rawName] => `event_comment`
                                            [allowNull] => 1
                                            [dbType] => text
                                            [type] => string
                                            [defaultValue] => 
                                            [size] => 
                                            [precision] => 
                                            [scale] => 
                                            [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                            [isForeignKey] => 
                                            [autoIncrement] => 
                                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                        )

                                )

                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                    [columns] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                (
                                    [name] => id
                                    [rawName] => `id`
                                    [allowNull] => 
                                    [dbType] => int(10) unsigned
                                    [type] => string
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [size] => 10
                                    [precision] => 10
                                    [scale] => 
                                    [isPrimaryKey] => 1
                                    [isForeignKey] => 
                                    [autoIncrement] => 1
                                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                )

                            [id_campain] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                (
                                    [name] => id_campain
                                    [rawName] => `id_campain`
                                    [allowNull] => 
                                    [dbType] => int(10) unsigned
                                    [type] => string
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [size] => 10
                                    [precision] => 10
                                    [scale] => 
                                    [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                    [isForeignKey] => 1
                                    [autoIncrement] => 
                                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                )

                            [id_customer] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                (
                                    [name] => id_customer
                                    [rawName] => `id_customer`
                                    [allowNull] => 
                                    [dbType] => int(10) unsigned
                                    [type] => string
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [size] => 10
                                    [precision] => 10
                                    [scale] => 
                                    [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                    [isForeignKey] => 1
                                    [autoIncrement] => 
                                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                )

                            [event_datetime] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                (
                                    [name] => event_datetime
                                    [rawName] => `event_datetime`
                                    [allowNull] => 1
                                    [dbType] => datetime
                                    [type] => string
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [size] => 
                                    [precision] => 
                                    [scale] => 
                                    [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                    [isForeignKey] => 
                                    [autoIncrement] => 
                                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                )

                            [event_type] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                (
                                    [name] => event_type
                                    [rawName] => `event_type`
                                    [allowNull] => 1
                                    [dbType] => varchar(200)
                                    [type] => string
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [size] => 200
                                    [precision] => 200
                                    [scale] => 
                                    [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                    [isForeignKey] => 
                                    [autoIncrement] => 
                                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                )

                            [event_status] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                (
                                    [name] => event_status
                                    [rawName] => `event_status`
                                    [allowNull] => 1
                                    [dbType] => varchar(200)
                                    [type] => string
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [size] => 200
                                    [precision] => 200
                                    [scale] => 
                                    [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                    [isForeignKey] => 
                                    [autoIncrement] => 
                                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                )

                            [event_comment] => CMysqlColumnSchema Object
                                (
                                    [name] => event_comment
                                    [rawName] => `event_comment`
                                    [allowNull] => 1
                                    [dbType] => text
                                    [type] => string
                                    [defaultValue] => 
                                    [size] => 
                                    [precision] => 
                                    [scale] => 
                                    [isPrimaryKey] => 
                                    [isForeignKey] => 
                                    [autoIncrement] => 
                                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [relations] => Array
                        (
                            [relCustomer] => CBelongsToRelation Object
                                (
                                    [joinType] => LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                    [on] => 
                                    [alias] => 
                                    [with] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [together] => 
                                    [scopes] => 
                                    [name] => relCustomer
                                    [className] => customer
                                    [foreignKey] => id_customer
                                    [select] => *
                                    [condition] => 
                                    [params] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [group] => 
                                    [join] => 
                                    [having] => 
                                    [order] => 
                                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                )

                            [idCampain] => CBelongsToRelation Object
                                (
                                    [joinType] => LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                    [on] => 
                                    [alias] => 
                                    [with] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [together] => 
                                    [scopes] => 
                                    [name] => idCampain
                                    [className] => TblCampain
                                    [foreignKey] => id_campain
                                    [select] => *
                                    [condition] => 
                                    [params] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [group] => 
                                    [join] => 
                                    [having] => 
                                    [order] => 
                                    [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                                    [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                                )

                        )

                    [attributeDefaults] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [_model:CActiveRecordMetaData:private] => customerCampain Object
                        (
                            [_md:CActiveRecord:private] => CActiveRecordMetaData Object
 *RECURSION*
                            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
                            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
                            [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 
                            [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
                            [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [_validators:CModel:private] => 
                            [_scenario:CModel:private] => 
                            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
                            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
                        )

                )

            [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2155
                    [id_campain] => 4
                    [id_customer] => 109
                    [event_datetime] => 
                    [event_type] => 
                    [event_status] => 
                    [event_comment] => ******IneedOfThisValue*****
                )

            [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => 
            [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 2155
            [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t
            [_errors:CModel:private] => Array
                (
                )

            [_validators:CModel:private] => 
            [_scenario:CModel:private] => update
            [_e:CComponent:private] => 
            [_m:CComponent:private] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: If your relation is HAS_MANY then `rel_CustomerCampain` will be an array, that's why you get this error, so is your relation HAS_MANY ?

Comment: What is that print_r output from?  `print_r($data)`,  `print_r($data->rel_CustomerCampain)`, or something else ?

Comment: is print_r($data->rel_CustomerCampain,false)

Comment: But I don't understand how I can have the value of event_comment

Comment: show the model's relations function, please. things will be clear then. you can edit the question and add the relation function code.

Comment: public function relations()
    {
     // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
     return array(
     //customerCampainI
      'relCustomer' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'customer', 'id_customer'),
         'idCampain' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'TblCampain', 'id_campain'),
     );
    }

Comment: there is onlu two relation, thanks in advance for your help

Comment: need to see the relations of the current model, for which you are displaying this gridview, i'm guessing it's the customer model. so please show the relations in customer model, (if the gridview is for customer model). And you can tag me with @bool.dev, so that i get notified of your replies.

Comment: public function relations()
 {
  // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
  // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
  return array(
   'rel_CustomerCampain' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'customerCampain', 'id_customer'),
   //VAR=>array(tipoRel,NomeClasse,Campo fk)
   'rel_location' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Location', 'location_id'),
  );
 }

Answer (score 1):

As i was suspecting<sup>1</sup>, your current model, i.e the one for which you are displaying the gridview, has a `HAS_MANY` relationship with the *CustomerCampain* model. This means `$data->rel_CustomerCampain` is an **array** of *CustomerCampain* objects, which can also be seen from your print_r output:

```
[0] => customerCampain Object
     (
      ...
     )
```

So instead of:

```
'value'=>'$data->rel_CustomerCampain->event_comment'
```

you have to do:

```
'value'=>'$data->rel_CustomerCampain[arrayIndex]->event_comment'
// here arrayIndex will have to be the index of the campain you are interested in
'value'=>'$data->rel_CustomerCampain[0]->event_comment' // 0 index for the first campain
```

---

(1): see first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200521/cactiverecord-and-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-error#comment16341485_12200521) to question

Comment: if i have missed out anything, you can always leave comments for clarifications